# Monitor configuration changes when reconnecting displayport-monitor

Tags: linux, display, multiple-monitors, displayport, nvidia-settings

I currently have a setup with 3 monitors: one connected via DVI, one via HDMI and one via DisplayPort (because these are the three connectors on my graphics card).

I configured them correctly using `nvidia-settings` and saved the config to the X configuration file (after running `nvidia-settings` with root to do this).

When I disconnect the DisplayPort-connected monitor the positions change: It doesn't show up in `nvidia-settings` anymore and when I reconnect it its position is reset. The other two monitors (HDMI, DVI) still show up in `nvidia-settings` when I turn them off.

The problem is that I have a power switch that controls all three monitors and the one that's connected to DisplayPort always seems to be the last one to connect to the pc (regardless of which monitor I connect with DisplayPort).

How can I reconfigure my X-Server (or Xfce if that's the issue) to put the third monitor in the correct position when reconnecting them?

Using:

- Arch Linux with X11, lightdm and Xfce
- Nvidia GTX-750Ti
  [image: <code>nvidia-settings</code>]

Comment: If anybody else runs into this problem: Connecting the third monitor with a DVI-DisplayPort-Adapter (where the DVI connector is at the monitor side) that I had lying around helped, but I would not consider buying hardware a solution to (what I think is) a software problem.